# Java wait for an object in another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

For the following example:

```
public Car getCar(int id){
    Car result= findCarInCache(id);
    if (result==null){
       // POINT A 
       return createCarWithId(id);
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}

public Car findCarInCache(int id){
    // Do something for find a car with this id in the cache
}

public void addToCache(Car car){
    // Add the car to the cache
}

public Car createCarWithId(int id){
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    Car result= new Car(id);
    addToCache(Car);
    return result;
}
```

The problem comes when two Threads call at the same time getCar(2) for example. Then both threads reach the POINT A, and two instances of the Car#2 are generated. How can I make the second thread to wait at the POINT A, until the first thread finish the creation and then return the same object in both calls? (I'm doing this in Android)

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/. Or similarly, a beginner's book on java. If you're using threads, you need to understand concurrency

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right way would be to add a `synchronized` section somewhere which makes sure that only one thread can enter the block at the same time.

You asked specifically about `POINT A` so you could make the `createCarWithId` be synchronized.

```
public synchronized Car createCarWithId(int id){
```

This will lock on the `this` of the Object who has that method.  Here's some documentation on [`synchronized` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

However, you need to protect both the addition of the `Car` to the cache *and* the finding it in the cache since multiple threads will be using the cache simultaneously.  For this reason you also need to make the `findCarInCache` `synchronized`.  Also, since you don't want to lock twice in `getCar`, it should also probably be `synchronized`:

```
public synchronized Car getCar(int id){
...
public synchronized Car findCarInCache(int id){
...
public synchronized Car createCarWithId(int id){
```

If you want to reduce the scope of your lock, as an alternative you can create a lock object that you can `synchronize` on:

```
private final Object lockObject = new Object();
...

public Car getCar(int id){
   synchronized (lock) {
      ...
   }
}
public Car findCarInCache(int id){
   synchronized (lock) {
      ...
   }
}
public Car createCarWithId(int id){
   synchronized (lock) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Here's more documentation on [lock objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is very usefull. So if I want the method createCarWithId() to be synchronized but only between the cars with the same id I should implement some kind of singleton retrieve the lockObject associated with that id, right? Or is there an easier form?

Comment: No, I don't think you need the lock with that much limited scope @Addev.  I would just have a synchronized block around the add and cache put and leave it at that.  Even though the only time you care about the race is if the id is the same, creating some sort of map of locks on a per-id basis would also require synchronization so it's not worth it.

Comment: Also @Addev, your cache would also need to be synchronized so you might want to really lock `getCar` as well as `createCarWithId`.  Anything you are altering in multiple threads (cache) needs to be protected.  I'm going to edit my response.